# In Heroku, is it possible to assign one env var to another env var?

Tags: heroku

By using https://github.com/mars/heroku-js-runtime-env-buildpack I'm having my frontend pick up some run-time envvars from the server. The problem I have is that it only picks up environment variables with names starting with `JS_RUNTIME_` and I want to pick `HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION`.

Is there a way to make Heroku somehow set `JS_RUNTIME_HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION` to the same value as `HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION`?

Comment: Does `heroku config:set JS_RUNTIME_HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION='$HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION'`, with single quotes around the existing config var, work?

Comment: @Chris: it doesn't, it just contains the string without interpolating the variable :(

Comment: And why do you need this variable at runtime? Can't you compile it into your JavaScript at build time?

Comment: @Chris: that variable it's not correctly available at compile time. Others might be different between staging and production (connecting to different API endpoints for example).